# Will my roza (fasting) be accepted or not?

Tags: sawm, nafl

I kept nafil roza (fasting) and I came to know that I was mistaken about the azan time; I ate the sehri (pre-dawn meal) 15 minutes after the azan so will this roza (fast) be considered or not? Or do I have to repeat it?

Comment: What one can definitely say is now as you know it you shouldn't repeat this mistake again. Note that Allah prefers to be worshiped by knowledge. It was your duty to get all necessary information before starting to fast.